# Create counter column family in cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, thrift, cassandra-2.0, hector

I am using cassandra-2.0.10 and hector api.

I have tried :

```
    public static void createCounterColumnFamily(Keyspace keyspace, String ccfName) {   
    Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace,StringSerializer.get());
    mutator.addCounter("salary", ccfName, HFactory.createCounterColumn("salary", 10L));
    mutator.execute();}
```

But, I'm getting this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured columnfamily counter_column_family_1)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:45)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:265)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecuteOperation(ExecutingKeyspace.java:113)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
    at com.cassandra.practice.CounterColumnFamily.createCounterColumnFamily(CounterColumnFamily.java:18)
    at com.cassandra.practice.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:33)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured columnfamily counter_column_family_1)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:20833)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:964)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:950)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.execute(MutatorImpl.java:246)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:104)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:258)
    ... 4 more
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly create both the column family and the keyspace before you can insert data.

That said the Hector API was deprecated more than five years ago and the Cassandra version you are using is just as far behind. More significantly, the Thrift API has been deprecated completely for years and has already been removed from trunk in the upcoming 4.0 release.

Please switch to 3.11.4 of Cassandra available here:
http://cassandra.apache.org/download/

And to using CQL and the java driver for such available here:
https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.x/manual

Out of curiosity, how did you come across the versions you are currently using?

Comment: **"Hector API was deprecated more than five years ago and the Cassandra version you are using is just as far behind"** I wish I could upvote this answer more than once.

Comment: <3 Aaron!! I felt like this last commit summed it up, but :( https://github.com/hector-client/hector/commit/a302e68ca8d91b45d332e8c9afd7d98030b54de1

Comment: yeah I did that and after that I'm calling this method.